# how to solve recurrence T(n) = T(n/3)+ T(sqrt(n)) + loglog n

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, recurrence-relations, asymptotics, computer-science

Could someone give me advice on how to solve the following recurrence:
$T(n) = T\left(\frac{n}{3}\right) + T(\sqrt{n}) + \log \log n$

Thanks.

Comment: Just what set is this function supposed to be defined on? For most integers, the arguments will be non-integer. I suppose it could be defined on the algebraic numbers, but that doesn't qualify as "discrete". Was this a real problem, or something you threw together?